# JQuery: Refresh div or append for uploading comments?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on uploading comments through AJAX. The basic function is a comment upload box on top of a list of already uploaded comments. When a new comment is submitted, the list gets updated.

Question: should I use the JQuery append() method to append the new comment to the list, or should I use AJAX to refresh the comment list?

HTML

Upload comment:

```
  <textarea  name='comment'>Put in comment</textarea>
  <button type="button">Publish Comment</button>
```

Comment list

```
 <?php foreach ($comment->result() as $row): 
 $parent_comment_id=$row->parent_comment_id;
 if($parent_comment_id==$comment_id)
 {?>

 <div class='comment_list'>
 <?php echo $row->body; ?>
 </div>
```

If I were to use the append() method, then would I need to pass all the php variables such as $parent_comment_id back through AJAX?

If I were to use the refresh method, what would be the way to implement it?

Thanks a lot,

Here are the actual existing code to list out the comments: there are a few php variables that need to pass through. Of course I don't expect you to show me everything, but a general direction on what I need to do would be very helpful:

```
    <!-- start of replies -->
            <?php foreach ($reply->result() as $row): 
                $parent_comment_id=$row->parent_comment_id;
                if($parent_comment_id==$comment_id)
                {
            ?>
            <hr>
                <span class="subCommentArrow">&#10142;</span>
                <span>
                <div class="media">
                <img class="media-object pull-left" height=64 width=64 src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/image/avatar/<?php echo $row->avatar ?>" alt="用户">
                <div class="media-body subCommentContainer">
                <p><!-- start of displaying replies -->
                    <div class="content">

                    <p class="username"><?php echo $row->username; ?>
                    <p><?php echo $row->body; ?></p>
                    </p>

                    </div>
                    <p align="right" class="commentTime"><?php echo date('Y-m-d h:i a', strtotime($row->time_stamp)); ?></p>


                        <p> <!-- Start of like/dislike for reply to replies -->
                        <?php $reply_id=$row->reply_id;

                        //display the reply_id from upvote table 
                        $query_reply_upvote=$this->db->query("select ip from upvote where interview_id='$interview_id' and reply_id='$reply_id'");
                        $count_reply_upvote=$query_reply_upvote->num_rows();


                        $query_reply_downvote=$this->db->query("select ip from downvote where interview_id='$interview_id' and reply_id='$reply_id'");
                        $count_reply_downvote=$query_reply_downvote->num_rows();
                        ?>

                        <span href="javascript:;" rel="<?php echo $row->reply_id; ?>" class="reply_upvote"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> +<?php echo $count_reply_upvote;?></a></span>     
                        <span href="javascript:;" rel="<?php echo $row->reply_id; ?>" class="reply_downvote"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> -<?php echo $count_reply_downvote;?></a></span>

                        </p> <!-- end of the like/dislike for reply to replies-->

                  </div> <!-- End of reply body --> 
                </div> <!-- End of reply div -->

                </span><!-- End of reply span -->
                <?php
                } 
                endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I think append will be a better choice as you don't have to load all contents again... then How to implement it? you need to share how the existing comment markup looks like

Comment: Thanks Arun. I added in the actual markup of existing comments for your review.